# Static page won't identify template

Tags: page-template, template-hierarchy

I have two pages, one working correctly and one broken.

The first is called Calendar and it has an ID of 34. I created a page template called page-34.php and wrote some custom code, and when I load the page the template is pulled correctly and the custom code displays correctly. I have a bunch of other pages on my site like this, and they work just like this.

And then I have the second, feisty page. It's name is FAQ and it has an ID of 35. I created a template called page-35.php and wrote some custom code, but when I load the page it just defaults to index.php.

To provide some background, I recently imported all of this content from a Drupal 7 site using a plugin. I'm wondering if something broke during that process. I'm a fairly experienced WordPress developer and I've done all my usual checks for this problem, so I'm at the point where I want to do a deeper debug.

**Question:** Does anyone know how to do a deep programmatic debug of the template hierarchy check? I'm not afraid to get my hands dirty in the database.

Comment: Check the classes of `<body>`, it could be loading an archive/etc., which usually overwrites custom pages

Comment: @kero Ahhh yep! That's it! Thank you so much. If you want to add this as an answer, I'll mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my personal experience, WP template hierarchy has worked without problems - so no major bug here. However, it may still be, that your `page-$id.php` is not used. This is usually the case, when the link could be multiple things. Archives for example have priority over regular pages.

Best is to check the CSS classes on `<body>` of that page, and you'll see what kind of internal page was loaded.